# Can't get CMAKE to compile a project

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, g++, mingw

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_86068\fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/--REDACTED--/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_86068\fast"

The system cannot find the file specified

Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_86068\fast"





CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/--REDACTED--/socket.io-client-cpp-1.6.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/--REDACTED--/socket.io-client-cpp-1.6.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

For the record I am using:

- gcc and g++ from MinGW 4.8.1
- CMake 3.4.1

I have no idea what the issue could be, I've looked extensively online and have not found anywhere where somebody has gotten a solution, except in cases where it had to do with path issues where the path included non-latin characters or no write access, which is not the case for any of the directories in question.  I seriously am about to give up completely on ever being able to get this to work, but I don't know what to do because I absolutely NEED the socket.io client for C++ for this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake is a utility which generates a "makefile" for different build systems. Here you generate a nmake makefile and it seems that you don't have nmake in your path.

You can launch CMake with option `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` in order to generate a makefile compatible with mingw make. Then issue the command:

```
mingw32-make
```

Comment: is nmake a .exe like gcc and g++?  Is it a part of MinGW?

Comment: nmake is part of Microsoft's Visual Studio. With mingw you should have a gmake compatible application. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I tried using mingw32-make instead of nmake, and got this:
The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
program.
It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/p63053/Desktop/FreeLoader Downloads/socket.io-client-cpp-1.6.1/socket.io-client-cpp-1.6.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"mingw32-make" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_5618c\fast"
Makefile:38: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: I need some clarification, because when I do cmake -G "MinGW MakeFiles" <other options> ./ it doesn't even try to make it, it says 'could not create named generator MinGW MakeFiles"

Comment: @ClintonJ `cmake --help` will output you the exact denomination to give to the -G option.

Comment: I am doing exactly what it says.  WHY does it think I'm trying to create a generator and not use the one that is there?

Comment: Figured that part out.  Now to figure out the next batch of errors.

Comment: @ClintonJ It's possible that your distribution of cmake does not support  this generator. But it should:  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html

Comment: It was a typo in the generator string.  I'm coming up with a whole list of additional errors, I've decided to go ahead and uninstall CMake and start looking for a different job.